# What is the "template" keyword doing before "class" keyword?

Tags: c++, templates

Just some code sample [Not a  real life example]

```
// at file scope

template <typename T, typename U>
struct demo{};  
template class demo<int, int>; // is the template keyword optional here?
```

Is the template keyword optional in line 3? I haven't (often) seen this usage of the template keyword before. Which part of the standard says allows this?

**EDIT**

I think g++ has a bug then.

```
template <typename T, typename U>
struct demo{};  
class demo<int, int>; // template keyword omitted
```

compiles on g++ (4.5.1) whereas fails on Comeau

```
"ComeauTest.c", line 5: error: specializing class "demo<int, int>" without
          "template<>" syntax is nonstandard
      class demo<int, int>;
```

Comment: I think I am missing something. :(

Comment: Try actually using `demo<int,int>` in an way in your code with GCC, it will reject it if you don't have the `template` keyword.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's an *explicit instantiation*.

Typically when you use a template, the compiler generates what you need, as you need it. To provide essential specializations of a class template in a static or dynamic library, however, you want to generate all the members, all at once, to make sure they are delivered to the user.

For example, most implementations of the C++ standard library explicitly specialize `std::ostream<char,char_traits<char> >`, because otherwise applications would end up including repetitive copies of various operations on `cout`.

This syntax is identical with explicit instantiation. C++03 §14.7.2/2:

> The syntax for explicit instantiation is:
>
> *explicit-instantiation:*
>
> `template` *declaration*

## Edit:

It looks like you stumbled on obsolete syntax for *specializing*, not explicitly instantiating, a class template. Comeau is warning you that it took the template-id declaration as a forward declaration of an explicit specialization. Presumably GCC is doing the same. It is unlikely that you are obtaining explicit instantiation in that case. Also, it is undefined behavior to use an explicit template specialization before it is defined. (Fundamentally, the implicit specialization causes a violation of the one-definition rule.)

Note that GCC also supports `extern` template instantiations:

> `extern template` *declaration*

In the case of an extern function instantiation, I would not be surprised if `template` were optional. But, neither would I be surprised to find it is required, nor omit it.

Comment: I am familiar with explicit instantiation. My question is "Is the template keyword optional there"?

Comment: @Prasoon: No. Why would it be?

Comment: @Potatoswatter : Then I think there is some bug in g++ because [this](http://ideone.com/pR7Su) compiles. I haven't downvoted you.

Comment: prasoon asked a specific question which has not yet been addressed in any answer.

Comment: @David: Failure to fully address the question is not a reason to downvote, and what have I not addressed?

Comment: @Potatoswatter : I think I am missing something. Edited my question.

Comment: failure to address the question is absolutely a reason for a downvote. The original answer just said, this is explicit instantiation. There was no attempt to address whether or not template keyword was optional. Even now it is poor. A good answer would address that issue directly and not go into spurious details that OP knows very well.

Comment: @David: The original answer explained what explicit instantiation *is*, and since when were keywords optional in general? "Spurious details"? WTF?

Comment: well a good answer would have been, "keywords are not optional". Your edits are adding lots more text but the answer to the question is getting harder to discern!

Comment: @David: So, saying only "keywords are not optional" is a good answer, but "spurious details of what he knows very well" are copping an attitude? Sorry, I'm not buying this philosophy.

Comment: It is my opinion that a more concise answer that directly addressed the question would be more valuable.

Comment: @David: And is the question not "What is the “template” keyword doing before “class” keyword?"

Comment: Question: "Is the template keyword optional?"

Comment: @David: As is often the case, the question in the title subsumes a number of questions in the body.

Comment: Well, maybe. And my opinion is just that, opinion. I appreciate that others have different opinions. Anyway, I just like really concise answers. For whatever reason, they seem scarce when the topic is C++.

Comment: @David: There's a bit of a clique among the C++ answerers, and it's not bad to check us now and then… but in questions that ask, "What part of the Standard allows this?" all bets are off.

Comment: @David: if you like concise answers so much, nobody is stopping you from writing one. If it's so important to you, do something about it yourself. And I believe "obsolete syntax" explains well that the keyword is *not* optional, and more.

Comment: @rubenvb I wouldn't write an answer because I am not in a position to do so.

Comment: Omitting is always pretty ambiguous. Did the user intend to write `class A<B> a;` and forgot the `a`? As a user, I would be confused about that much flexibility, and just want an error for `class A<B>;`.